# Firemonkey style in Listbox - retrieving data

Tags: image, delphi, listbox, firemonkey

I'm trying to get information from a Tlistbox in Firemonkey XE5 but it has an associated style where each item in the listbox includes an image, a memo and some buttons.

When clicking on the button inside the listbox style, I can get information from that item.

I want to get information from a the memo box in the listbox separately. Previously, I would have got the text from item 1 by using the following code:

```
NewString:=ListBox1.items[1];
```

However, now each item in the listbox has more than one piece of information.

I can add a new Listbox item using the code as follows:

```
var Item: TListBoxItem;

begin

Item := TListBoxItem.Create(nil);

Item.Parent := ListBox1;

Item.StyleLookup := 'PlaylistItem';

Item.StylesData['Memo1']:='test text';
```

But, how do I read just the memo box of a particular item

Thanks

Aman

---

Update.

The solution is

```
Tempstr:=ListBox1.ItemByIndex(1).StylesData['Memo1'].AsString;
```

I'm now trying to work out how to get an image out as there isn't a AsImage or AsBitmap suffix.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise subclassing TListBoxItem, then adding properties and methods to get/set the data from the style objects using FindStyleResource,

```
class TMemoListBoxItem = class(TListBoxItem)
protected
  function GetMemoText: String;
  procedure SetMemoText(const Text: String);  
published
  property MemoText: String read GetMemoText write SetMemoText;
end;

function TMemoListBoxItem.GetMemoText: String;
var O: TFMXObject;
begin
  O := FindStyleResource('Memo1');
  if O is TMemo then
    Result := TMemo(O).Text
  else
    Result := '';
end;

procedure TMemoListBoxItem.SetMemoText(const Text: String);
var O: TFMXObject;
begin
  O := FindStyleResource('Memo1');
  if O is TMemo then
    TMemo(O).Text := Text;
end;
```

And continue likewise for your other data.